# How can I intercept zooms in leaflet.js?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I would like all the zooms on my leaflet map to be centered around one point. So that no matter where the user zooms on the map, that one point always stays in the same place.

This point is not necessarily the center, but it is in a known position.

At the moment, I can intercept the zoom controls to do this, but I have been unable to find a way to intercept the double-click or mouse gestures.

Comment: I'll guess that this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and what you really want is the [Leaflet-active-area or the Leaflet.ControlledBounds plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#events).

Answer (score 0):

```
mapObject.on('zoomstart',(e) =>{
   //you can stop the event here and call your own function,
});
```

Comment: This still calls the default zooming, which I wanted to override. I hackily fixed my issue by overriding the `setZoomAround()` function.

Comment: You can disable maps zoom by settings

Comment: Note Map object also has properties like scroolToZoom and DblClickToZoom you can disable them and then manually set what ever zoom trigger you want

Comment: the problem with that approach is that there are no easy hooks to catch the touch events. For double click, that approach works.

Comment: you can use Hammer and Add a hammer event listener on ur map div.